# Getting the value of the first word from Args[1]

Tags: powershell

I have an script that automates an email every time another application runs. I use 2 variables from that application output to drive part of the subject of the email. My problem is the second variable is not a single item but a paragraph. I only need the very first word in order to pass that to the email subject. Looks something like this.

original app executes the following command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "alert_mail_test1.ps1" $ENTRY$ $TEXT$
```

The value of $ENTRY$ is a number

> 1234567

The value of $TEXT$ is paragraph

> From_South: this is your new entry. This paragraph might change in length but the first word is what tells me from were it is and where i have to send it.

Of course, if I do in my script

```
$location = args[1]
```

I get the entire paragraph. then I tried to break it in parts using a loop but the loop dont see the individual words, it always gives me the entire paragraph

```
$i=0
foreach ($word in $args)  {
       if ($i -eq 1) {
       $location = $word
       }
$i++
}
```

any help will be appreciated...

Comment: That is the format that the word will have. 2 words with an underscore and finishing with the colon. I dont care for the colon, it can stay or go, but the 2 words with the underscore will tell me if the email needs to be send and to who does it needs to be sent. thanks.

Comment: Figured as much... just wanted to be sure. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get "From_South" returned. Working with the following example of text in `$args[1]`

> From_South: this is your new entry. This paragraph might change in
>   length but the first word is what tells me from were it is and where i
>   have to send it.

I would probably use regex for this since you are just looking for the text between the first two word boundries

```
$location = $args[1] -replace "\b(.+?)\b.*",'$1'
```

`$location` in this case would be "From_South".

You could do a split returning 2 elements as well.

```
$location = $args[1].Split(" :",2))[0]
```

This would split on a colon or space. The two says that only two elements need be returned. The first one being "From_South"

Comment: `^(\w+):.*` (word at the beginning of a string, followed by a colon) might be a more appropriate expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
$location = $args[1].split(':')[0]
```

Comment: Wasn't sure if the colon was always there. But I have a split in my answer as well.

Comment: Yes, I missed that the when I first read it (didn't scroll down far enough).  You could also split on the space, and keep the colon. BTW, I think you have your parens out of balance in that split.

Comment: Yeah, fixed that on the script. I appreciate both of you guys.